# Java PreparedStatement.executeBatch() in SQLite not working

Tags: java, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have the following method. The commented methods saveOrUpdateToDatabase execute perfectly fine, but I would like to use the executeBatch. What am I missing? The int[]r which receives the executeBatch() results is always empty...

```
public boolean saveOrUpdate(MonitoredData mData) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement prep;
            String timeID = this.getTimeLastRowID();

            for (CpuData o : mData.getCpu()) {
                prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(String.format(
                        INSERT_CPU_USAGE, this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));
                prep.addBatch();
                // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_CPU_USAGE,
                // this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));
            }
            for (DiskData o : mData.getDisk()) {
                prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(String.format(
                        INSERT_DISK_USAGE, this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));
                prep.addBatch();
                // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_DISK_USAGE,
                // this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));

            }
            for (NetworkData o : mData.getNet()) {
                prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(String
                        .format(INSERT_NETWORK_USAGE, this.nodeID, timeID, o
                                .toString()));
                prep.addBatch();
                // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_NETWORK_USAGE,
                // this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));

            }

            prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(String.format(
                    INSERT_MEMORY_USAGE, this.nodeID, timeID, mData.getMem()
                            .toString()));
            // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_MEMORY_USAGE,
            // this.nodeID, timeID, mData.getMem().toString()));

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            int[] r = prep.executeBatch();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

            return true;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HistoricalDatabase.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Batches, but it looks like you are adding a batch for a preparedstatement, but then replacing that preparedstatement with a new one. In the end, you assign prep a new preparedstatement, but don't call to addBatch(), and then you call executeBatch(), so it looks like you are always executing the batch for the last preparedstatement, the one you never called addBatch() before.

Comment: It also looks like you are using your preparedStatement as a regular statement, since you are setting the parameters in the SQL string, instead of using the setters the PreparedStatement class provides.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What am I missing? The int[]r which receives the executeBatch() results is always empty...

You are using the `addBatch()` method incorrectly.  In your code you are doing:

```
for (CpuData o : mData.getCpu()) {
    // WRONG!! you can not prepare a new query each time
    prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_CPU_USAGE);
    prep.setObject(1, this.nodeID);
    prep.addBatch();
}
```

This *replaces* the prepared query each time.  You should only be calling `prepareStatement(...)` once per batch.  You should be doing something like the following.  You will have to change your insert statements to have `?` arguments:

```
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_CPU_USAGE);
for (CpuData o : mData.getCpu()) {
    prep.setObject(1, this.nodeID);
    prep.setObject(2, timeID);
    prep.setObject(3, o);
    prep.addBatch();
}
prep.executeBatch();
```

Notice that only one `prepareStatement()` call is being used.  This has `?` SQL argument entities in it that are then assigned in the loop with the `prep.setString(1, ...)`.  When the batch is ready to be executed you call `prep.executeBatch()` but this is *without* ever replacing the `prep` prepared statement which you are doing.

If you are trying to perform a series of *different* insert statements in a row in the same batch then you should look into turning off auto-commit, doing your statements, call commit, and then turn auto-commit back on. Something like:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
// statements prepared and executed here
// maybe no need for batch operations
...
conn.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: I think I have another problem. My INSERT_CPU_USAGE is "INSERT INTO CpuUsage (NODE_ID, TIME_ID, CORE_ID, USER, NICE, SYSMODE, IDLE, IOWAIT, IRQ, SOFTIRQ, STEAL, GUEST) VALUES (?, ?, ?);" As you saw before, I'm passing the node ID, the time and the third "?" is a string from the getCPu with all other values. But this lead me to "3 values for 12 columns" exception. It parsers the insert and compares to the number of ?'s? =/

Comment: Not sure I understand but the number of columns in your `INSERT` statement should match the number of `VALUES`.  `INSERT INTO CpuUsage (NODE_ID, TIME_ID, USER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`.  If `getCPu` returns "all of the other values" then you'll need to break them out and set them one by one and have 12 `?` fields.

Comment: Thank you Gray! I spend almost 4 hours trying to figure it out.. Funny thing that I knew adout it and still write incorrect in code :)

Answer (score -1):

Besides the comments I wrote, I'm going to risk giving an answer. What if you try something like this:

```
public boolean saveOrUpdate(MonitoredData mData) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement prep;
        String timeID = this.getTimeLastRowID();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        for (CpuData o : mData.getCpu()) {
            prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_CPU_USAGE);
            prep.setObject(1, this.nodeID);
            prep.setObject(2, timeID);
            prep.setObject(3, o);
            prep.addBatch();
            // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_CPU_USAGE,
            // this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));
        }
        prep.executeBatch();
        for (DiskData o : mData.getDisk()) {
            prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_DISK_USAGE);
            prep.setObject(1, this.nodeID);
            prep.setObject(2, timeID);
            prep.setObject(3, o);
            prep.addBatch();
            // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_DISK_USAGE,
            // this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));
        }
        prep.executeBatch();
        for (NetworkData o : mData.getNet()) {
            prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_NETWORK_USAGE);
            prep.setObject(1, this.nodeID);
            prep.setObject(2, timeID);
            prep.setObject(3, o);
            prep.addBatch();
            // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_NETWORK_USAGE,
            // this.nodeID, timeID, o.toString()));

        }
        prep.executeBatch();
        prep = this.conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_MEMORY_USAGE);
        prep.setObject(1, this.nodeID);
        prep.setObject(2, timeID);
        prep.setObject(3, o);
        prep.executeUpdate();
        // saveOrUpdateToDatabase(String.format(INSERT_MEMORY_USAGE,
        // this.nodeID, timeID, mData.getMem().toString()));

        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        return true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HistoricalDatabase.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You may need to modify those SQL query defined in the constants.

Comment: This suffers from the same bug as the OP.  He cannot prepare multiple statements that way.  See my post.

Comment: You are right, my intention was to set the assignment before the for, but I forgot to move it while copy pasting his code. Sorry

Comment: You sure you don't want to delete or edit this dude?